# Solving standard normal CDF for variable

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have the following standard normal CDF
$$\max \Phi(2\times\sqrt{n}(c_1-0.48)) = 0.025$$
$$\max P(Z<2\times\sqrt{n}(c_1-0.48)) = 0.025$$

I am trying to get the value for $c_1$.

Is it correct to set $Z = 1.96$ (since 0.025 quantile) and then set
$$1.96 = 2\times\sqrt{n}(c_1-0.48)$$

Solving for $c_1 = \frac{1.96}{2\sqrt{n}}+0.48$

Seems I am going wrong somewhere..

Comment: I dunno what the max is about (I guess you want the biggest $c_1$ such that the LHS is $\leq 0.025$), but otherwise you want $-1.96$ as you can see by thinking of the picture.

Comment: Yes i see, since we have the lower tail of the distribution. I did the same thing with the upper bound and it worked well now. Thank you, I think this picture stuck with me now:)